# how to add padding between menu items in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar

[image]

I'm having menu items being inflated from res/menu/menu.xml on to ActionBar, how do I add padding between menu items using android?

```
<item 
    android:id="@+id/home"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="Home"
    android:icon="@drawable/homeb"/>
<item 
    android:id="@+id/location"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="Locations"
    android:icon="@drawable/locationb"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/preQualify"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="Pre-Qualify"
    android:icon="@drawable/prequalityb"/>
<item 
    android:id="@+id/products"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="Products"
    android:icon="@drawable/productb"/>
```

Java file:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_store_locator, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Found solution, added following lines in styles.xml file and it worked!!

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:actionButtonStyle">@style/MyActionButtonStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionButtonStyle" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:minWidth">20dip</item>
    <item name="android:padding">0dip</item>
</style>
```

Comment: The important thing is "minWidth" it's 80dp by default. Which means even without padding there can be some space. That was the problem in my case.

Comment: How can i use this style in my menu item ?? If you share simple code , it will be helpful 
Thanks

Comment: I noticed that our theme style and "MyActionButtonStyle" should have the same parent name

Comment: Works fine.  I created styles.xml in res/values, added the style.  I had to change the AppTheme to match theme in the manifest file and themes file.  I just wonder what else uses the android:actionButtonStyle though...

Answer (score 9):

create drawable xml . like `res/drawable/shape_green_rect.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:shape="rectangle">

  <!-- Specify a semi-transparent solid green background color -->
  <solid android:color="#5500FF66" />

  <!-- Specify a dark green border -->
  <stroke 
    android:width="5dp"
    android:color="#009933" />

  <!-- Specify the margins that all content inside the drawable must adhere to -->
  <padding
    android:left="30dp"
    android:right="30dp"
    android:top="30dp"
    android:bottom="30dp" />
</shape>
```

Add this drawable in

```
android:icon="@drawable/shape_green_rect"
```

This way we can able to add padding in menu.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!! If I add `android:icon="@drawable/shape_green_rect"` where do I add my icons in the xml file?

Answer (score -2):

Padding I don't know, but you can add margin by the following way:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
lp.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);
yourItem.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

Set your values instead of "left, top, right, bottom". In this example I'm adding margin on an item that you would get with its ID.

Hope this helps.

Comment: you should be more specific on `yourItem` because 'MenuItem.setLayoutParams' does not work!