# how to change space size between widget toolbar icons on Android?

Tags: android, toolbar

I have a Toolbar widget on my App with 4 icons and I want to change the space size between these icons to be the same.

Form this:
[current design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRItw.png)

To be like this:
[wanted design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4f2UX.png)

menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_home"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:icon="@drawable/white_home"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    app:showAsAction="always" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_profile"
    android:orderInCategory="101"
    android:icon="@drawable/white_profile"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    app:showAsAction="always" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_inbox"
    android:orderInCategory="102"
    android:icon="@drawable/white_inbox"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    app:showAsAction="always" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_contacts"
    android:orderInCategory="103"
    android:icon="@drawable/white_contacts"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    app:showAsAction="always" />
```

app_bar_main.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_fab_plus"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary" />
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @ Khalil Jomaa please sens your xml file here

Comment: Post your *Layout* code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an [example](https://gist.github.com/dodgex/7bc81fd2cbb70a8d5117) of how you can hack your Toolbar to place items in it filling all its width.

Main point is that you need to declare your own Toolbar's inheritor in which you override `addView` method:

```
@Override
public void addView(View child, ViewGroup.LayoutParams params) {
    if (child instanceof ActionMenuView) {
        params.width = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    }
    super.addView(child, params);
}
```

**UPDATED**

**If** you want to be able to modify space between action items through xml and don't want to extend `Toolbar.class` and also you use your toolbar as action bar (I meed you calling `setSupportActionBar()`) **then** you [can chang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15678467/how-to-add-padding-between-menu-items-in-android)e your application theme in `styles.xml` resource file:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:actionButtonStyle">@style/MyActionButtonStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionButtonStyle" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:minWidth">20dp</item>
    <item name="android:padding">0dp</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks Michael, but I wondered if I can do that by editing the XML layout or creating a custom toolbar style.

Comment: @KhalilJomaa Did that help you?