# How to add padding to actionbar overflow menu items?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to increase the size of the popup menu items in my toolbar's overflow menu. I've managed to increase the text size with the following in the base application theme.

```
<item name="android:textAppearanceLargePopupMenu">@style/menu_item</item>
```

And the following style.

```
<style name="menu_item" parent="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.PopupMenu.Large">
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_regular</item>
</style>
```

Now, however, I'm stuck trying to get the padding right, as the items appear too close together, as well as there is very little space on either edge of the popup menu overall.

Popup Menu:
[image]

Things I have tried:

- Adding padding to the menu_item style.
- Adding various different style items to the base theme with the desired padding.

  - actionButtonStyle: No effect.
  - popupMenuStyle: No effect.
  - listMenuViewStyle: No effect.
- Adding the following to the base theme. This did work to separate the items from each other, however the side padding obviously remained unchanged, and as a result looked disproportionate.

`<item name="android:listPreferredItemHeightSmall">64dp</item>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to add padding between menu items in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15678467/how-to-add-padding-between-menu-items-in-android)