# How to set margin to the android menu icon in the navigation drawer?

Tags: android, xml, android-styles

I have a navigation drawer. I have changed the text appearance with adding style but how about adding a margin to the icons:

```
<resources>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/IranSansTextViewStyle</item>
</style>
<style name="IranSansTextViewStyle" parent="android:Widget.TextView">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/iransansmobile</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#FF383838</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

and my NavigationView:

```
  <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/drawer_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"
    app:itemTextAppearance="@style/IranSansTextViewStyle"
    >
```

Comment: You can set a custom layout to your navigationview. Also you can set padding values for all navigation items. app:itemIconPadding="??"

Comment: check this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15679629/7586266
and this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/10808259/7586266

Comment: or pre-draw the margins to each of your icons.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this line to the NavigationView:

```
 android:paddingRight="8dp"
```

Note: this will pad your icons and text to the right.